# How will Exeggcute evolve?

Tags: pokemon-go

With the recent addition of the Alolan Exeggutor form, will Exeggcute evolve to the old form, or the new one (with a different move pool and types)?

It will not be like the main series, because it depends where (in-game) you evolve it. From [Bulbapedia](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Exeggutor_(Pok%C3%A9mon)) (emph mine):

> In Alola, Exeggutor has a regional variant that is Grass/Dragon. It evolves from Exeggcute when exposed to a Leaf Stone. **All Exeggcute in Alola evolve into this form regardless of their origin.**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At the moment in time, there is no clear indication on how to obtain Alolan Exeggutor through evolving. I, as well with users on [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/pokemongo/comments/8n4nhx/alolan_exeggutor_discovered/), evolved Exeggcutes and they evolved into a normal Exeggutors.

Based on the [announcement](https://pokemongo.nianticlabs.com/en/post/pokemonletsgo/), it seems to be implied that it can only be obtained through catching for now. The initial [announcement](https://pokemongo.nianticlabs.com/en/post/alolakanto-pokemon/) of Alolan forms states Niantic will be releasing additional news in regards to this, so there are sure to be additional announcements in the future.

I looked through the Pokédex for Pokémon who have evolution variants just to be sure, and the Pokédex shows which Pokémon can evolve into the different forms.

[image: Poliwag Evolutions] [image: Wurmple Evolutions]

Exeggcute simple doesn't have that, and Alolan Exeggutor is shown as an alternative form of Exeggcutor alone.

[image: Exeggcute Evolutions] [image: Exeggcutor Evolutions]